# Doctrine 2 and Relations

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I have 2 tables. First table contains list of pilots, second contains ID's of pilots (foreign key).

Pilots tables.

```
<?php

namespace DCS\Entity;
/**
 *
 *
 * @Table(name="pilots")
 * @Entity
 *
 */
class Pilots
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $nickname
     *
     * @Column(name="nickname", type="string", length=128, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $nickname;
```

Second Table(list of spectators).

```
<?php

namespace DCS\Entity;
/**
 * DCS\Entity\DcsSpectators
 *
 * @Table(name="dcs_spectators")
 * @Entity
 */
class DcsSpectators
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer $pilotId
     * @Column(name="pilot_id", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $pilotId;
```

How to store right relations in annotations of these classes? 
In result, I want have a list of spectators from DcsSpectators with joined nicknames Pilots table. 
I've tried many ways, but no one won't work.

I'm trying to get data using `getRepository()` method and after - i'm calling `findAll()` method, but in result, I have only records from DcsSpectators Entity, without nicknames from `Pilots` table.

```
  <?php

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        $this->doctrine = Zend_Registry::get('doctrine');
        $this->entityManager = $this->doctrine->getEntityManager();
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $pilots = new DCS\Entity\Pilots();
        $red = new DCS\Entity\DcsRedteam();
        $blue = new DCS\Entity\DcsBlueteam();
        $spectators = $this->entityManager->getRepository('DCS\Entity\DcsSpectators')->findAll();
        foreach($spectators as $spectator){
            echo "<pre>";
            var_dump($spectator);
        }
        $info = $pilots->getMainPageInfo($this->entityManager);
        $redteam = $red->getList($this->entityManager);
        $blueteam = $blue->getList($this->entityManager);

        $this->view->redteam = $redteam;
        $this->view->blueteam = $blueteam;
        $this->view->flight_players = $info;
    }

}
```

So, what relation should I use to get correct DATA? 
And how to write this relation in annotations - correctly...?
Is it possible to generate sql query with correctly stored relations in annotations - like `SELECT dcs_spectators.*, pilots.nickname FROM dcs_spectators INNER JOIN pilots on pilots.id=dcs_spectators.pilot_id`???
I'm not interested in `createQuery` and `queryBuilder` things.

And one more question.

How can I check SQL query, which is generating by `findAll()` method (using `getRepository()`)?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere above where you are mapping entities with each other so first of all you need to tell the ORM that these entities are mapped this way. So you can query them accordingly :)

It should be modified as below:

In `2nd Entity DcsSpectators`

```
<?php

namespace DCS\Entity;
/**
 * DCS\Entity\DcsSpectators
 *
 * @Table(name="spectators")
 * @Entity
 */
class DcsSpectators
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */

    private $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(
     *   targetEntity="DCS\Entity\Pilots",
     *   inversedBy="spectators"
     * )
     * @var \DCS\Entity\Pilots
     */
    private $pilot;
}
```

In `1st Entity Pilots`:

```
<?php

namespace DCS\Entity;
/**
 *
 *
 * @Table(name="pilot")
 * @Entity
 *
 */
class Pilots
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $nickname
     *
     * @Column(name="nickname", type="string", length=128, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $nickname;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(
     *   targetEntity="DCS\Entity\DcsSpectators",
     *   mappedBy="pilot",
     *   cascade={"all"}
     * )
     * @var \DCS\Entity\DcsSpectators
     */
    protected $spectators;

}
```

It is very important to create `$spectators` in Pilots you may also write down it's getter according to your needs. But you now can try the given solution. Please replace the previous code with this one and let me know if it resolve your problem.

I think you are querying it in wrong direction as well. Doesn't it more sense to query `Spectators` on `Pilots` instead of querying through a foreign key :)
But no worries you can extract the data both ways when you are using the associations properly:

```
$spectators = $this->entityManager->getRepository('DCS\Entity\Pilots')->findAll();
foreach($spectators as $spectator){
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($spectator);
}
echo "Pilots >>>";
$pilots = $this->entityManager->getRepository('DCS\Entity\Pilots')->findAll();
foreach($pilots as $pilot){
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($pilot);
}

Output 1:
Pilots >>>
object(stdClass)#452 (4) {
  ["__CLASS__"]=>
  string(34) "Wishlocker\AppBundle\Entity\Pilots"
  ["id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["nickname"]=>
  string(5) "imran"
  ["spectators"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(41) "Wishlocker\AppBundle\Entity\DcsSpectators"
  }
}
object(stdClass)#452 (4) {
  ["__CLASS__"]=>
  string(34) "Wishlocker\AppBundle\Entity\Pilots"
  ["id"]=>
  int(2)
  ["nickname"]=>
  string(4) "john"
  ["spectators"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(41) "Wishlocker\AppBundle\Entity\DcsSpectators"
    [1]=>
    string(41) "Wishlocker\AppBundle\Entity\DcsSpectators"
  }
}
object(stdClass)#452 (4) {
  ["__CLASS__"]=>
  string(34) "Wishlocker\AppBundle\Entity\Pilots"
  ["id"]=>
  int(3)
  ["nickname"]=>
  string(4) "bizz"
  ["spectators"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(41) "Wishlocker\AppBundle\Entity\DcsSpectators"
  }
}

echo "<br><br>Spectators >>>";
$spectators = $this->entityManager->getRepository('DCS\Entity\DcsSpectators')->findAll();
foreach($spectators as $spectator){
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($spectator);
}

Output 2:

Spectators >>>
object(stdClass)#476 (3) {
  ["__CLASS__"]=>
  string(41) "Wishlocker\AppBundle\Entity\DcsSpectators"
  ["id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["pilot"]=>
  object(stdClass)#492 (4) {
    ["__CLASS__"]=>
    string(34) "Wishlocker\AppBundle\Entity\Pilots"
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["nickname"]=>
    string(5) "imran"
    ["spectators"]=>
    string(8) "Array(1)"
  }
}
object(stdClass)#476 (3) {
  ["__CLASS__"]=>
  string(41) "Wishlocker\AppBundle\Entity\DcsSpectators"
  ["id"]=>
  int(2)
  ["pilot"]=>
  object(stdClass)#486 (4) {
    ["__CLASS__"]=>
    string(34) "Wishlocker\AppBundle\Entity\Pilots"
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["nickname"]=>
    string(4) "john"
    ["spectators"]=>
    string(8) "Array(2)"
  }
}
object(stdClass)#476 (3) {
  ["__CLASS__"]=>
  string(41) "Wishlocker\AppBundle\Entity\DcsSpectators"
  ["id"]=>
  int(3)
  ["pilot"]=>
  object(stdClass)#490 (4) {
    ["__CLASS__"]=>
    string(34) "Wishlocker\AppBundle\Entity\Pilots"
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["nickname"]=>
    string(4) "john"
    ["spectators"]=>
    string(8) "Array(2)"
  }
}
object(stdClass)#476 (3) {
  ["__CLASS__"]=>
  string(41) "Wishlocker\AppBundle\Entity\DcsSpectators"
  ["id"]=>
  int(4)
  ["pilot"]=>
  object(stdClass)#474 (4) {
    ["__CLASS__"]=>
    string(34) "Wishlocker\AppBundle\Entity\Pilots"
    ["id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["nickname"]=>
    string(4) "bizz"
    ["spectators"]=>
    string(8) "Array(1)"
  }
}
```

I'm also attaching the table schema that I've used, the primary/foreign keys relation is not shown but don't worry about that. Remember to make sure you are using the same column names.[image]

For good understanding of these terms you need to a look [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html)

Another good explanation of these associations is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514365/doctrine2-one-to-many-many-to-one-relations)

Comment: Yes, i didn't map, because i wanted to know how it should be better and correct. Thanks for response. ....So, and, how about debug? How can i debug my relations? Is there any methods in doctrine 2, which are debugging getRepository with `find` methods?

Comment: Si the correct way is mentioned above. Show some favor in case this is what you were looking for :)

Comment: Imran, i don't uderstand. Your example won't work.So, there is my code : First, dcs_spectators Entity - `*  @ORM\OneToMany(
     *    targetEntity="DCS\Entity\Pilots",
     *   mappedBy="id",
     *   cascade={"all"}
     * )
     * @JoinColumn(name="nickname", referencedColumnName="id")` and second - Pilots Entity - `     * @ORM\ManyToOne(
     *   targetEntity="DCS\Entity\DcsSpectators",
     *   inversedBy="pilot_id"
     * )
     * @var \FOS\MessageBundle\Model\MessageInterface`...

Comment: By the way, in `Pilots` entity, at line `@var \FOS\MessageBundle\Model\MessageInterface` - the `Model` word is highlighted by Red color. Why?

Comment: At the end, i get this var_dump - `object(DCS\Entity\DcsSpectators)#115 (3) {
  ["id":"DCS\Entity\DcsSpectators":private]=>
  int(1)
  ["pilotId":"DCS\Entity\DcsSpectators":private]=>
  int(2)
  ["data":"DCS\Entity\DcsSpectators":private]=>
  object(DateTime)#113 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2015-12-02 00:00:00"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(15) "Europe/Helsinki"
  }
}`      as you can see, without joined data.

Comment: And there is one strange thing. When i'm store any relations and many times with mistakes  - on my called page i don't see any errors and et.c

Comment: I ll come up with full classes as I went to bed. You are again doing it wrong.

Comment: Before the example solution was provided but now I mapped everything according to your classes please update the solution and let me know.

Comment: Do remember to query it this way as well:

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not working. and when i'm running
`
$spectators = $this->entityManager->getRepository('DCS\Entity\Pilots')->findAll();
    foreach($spectators as $spectator){
        echo "<pre>"; var_dump($spectator);
    }
`
i'm getting the list of all pilots from Pilots table(Entity)...so, i don't need this info. The idea is, when the player joins game, i want to store info about him in another table, DcsSpectators, so i don't want to store his Nickname here, just his ID and dateTime.

Comment: @ICS_Vortex: The solution is now tested and updated fully for you I've also included the DB schema. So please accept it and show some positives :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but i don't understand a little bit. In first entity you're writing `class Pilots`, in the second entity you're writing the same name of the class...maybe you miss something? Can you show your code of TestRepository class? or, just upload these entities on some resource, like yandex disc or google disc

Comment: Sorry, about that I updated the solution again. Don't worry about `TestRepo`. The code from that is already pasted above for debug data :)

Comment: Thanks for all you did, if you don't mind, let's start from the beginning of your code. because, i still have problems. Really, i want to understand how works doctrine. DcsSpectators entity said to me that `is not a valid entity or mapped super class.` and after, i've added `@Entity` into annotation. After it said that table spectators not found. I've changed `@Table(name="dcs_spectators")` into nottations. And after, for Pilots class `Class DCS\Entity\Pilots is not a valid entity or mapped super class.`. I've added `@Table(name="pilots")`. but....see next comment

Comment: When i'm trying to add `@Entity` into nottation - i have next error `
Warning: require(/var/www/html/ORM/application/../library/DCS/Entity/Proxy/DCSEntityPilotsProxy.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/ORM/library/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php on line 85`....what i'm doing wrong? I've just edited my entities. THere are other fields in Polits ENtity, but we don't care about it, they are useless...email, password, licence and e.t.c

Comment: Actually I used `doctrine2` with `Symfony2` so please at least change the super class name to what Zend recommends.

Comment: Please send your complete classes to me as they were before. I ll encorporate changes in them and send back yo you. So you can get everything up and running.

Comment: You should ve removed this line `use Doctrine\Mapping as ORM;`

Comment: I ve made changes again under namespace to make it how your classes were defined. Please specify correct entities in tables herr ` @Table(name="spectators")` and `@Table(name="pilot")`. I ve put my effort to resolve your issue so plz try it correctly.

Comment: please, write me on skype Vortex_Bass if you can.